# how to store the return value of https POSTmethod in C#

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, dropbox

let just say i want to save the value of the

```
 POST` method "[https://api.dropbox.com/1/oauth/request_token][1]"
```

in a variable called

```
 `accessToken` of type `string`
```

`(lets just asume that the post method retuns string for the sake of simplicity)`
 in c# ..
How to do it ?

Comment: There are many ways to do it. How did you tied to implement it? What was wrong with your code?

Comment: I am new to c# programming ,can you help me out with some links to tutorials  ..PLZ

Comment: In your tags, do you mean string instead of spring?

Comment: You should check what dropbox suggest it self. [Here is a list of libraries](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/other) for many programming languages.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you have to decalre a string variable, like this:

```
string httpReturnValue = "";
```

To get the value and store it in the string you have to do this:

```
var request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("YOUR URL");

// For example
var postData = "thing1=hello";
    postData += "&thing2=world";

var data = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(postData);

request.Method = "POST";
request.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
request.ContentLength = data.Length;

using (var stream = request.GetRequestStream())
{
    stream.Write(data, 0, data.Length);
}

var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

var httpReturnValue= new StreamReader(response.GetResponseStream()).ReadToEnd();
```

The code is from here: [HTTP request with post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4015346/2630261).

Answer (score 1):

Hi Avik I use this code for obtain my HttpWebResponse:

```
using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)await request.GetResponseAsync())
                    {
                        if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                        {
                            //To obtain response body
                            using (Stream streamResponse = response.GetResponseStream())
                            {
                                using (StreamReader streamRead = new StreamReader(streamResponse, Encoding.UTF8))
                                {
                                    var result = streamRead.ReadToEnd();

                                    if (response.Equals("1")) //It's 1 in my case when operation                           is complete!!
                                    {

                                    }
                                    else
                                    {

                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
```

I think you can use this, if you need more info or u can solve with my code advise me! Good luck AviK!